# 'of' three times in a sentence

Tags: sentence-construction, redundancy

How do I say the exact same without using 'of' three times?

> This video contains a lot **of** footage **of** well-known events **of** the last 80 years.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

> This video contains extensive footage of well-known events from the last 80 years.

"Contain" works fine here, but if you want to emphasize the footage in the video, you can use "*feature*"

> This video *features* extensive footage of well-known events from the past 80 years.

Comment: Thanks! Is the following sentence okay? The video doesn't contain any flashbacks, but it does contain extensive footage of well known events from the past 80 years.

Comment: @Rowan Yeah it is a valid sentence.

Comment: thanks again! But what is the exact meaning of 'extensive'? Google says: covering or affecting a large area. But I don't think this is what you mean.